# Javascript, How to read hint values the user selected, from the input field?

Tags: javascript

I have notices that when I input data, the input field shows a hint.

If I select it, it becomes value of the field, but JavaScript does not see it, unless i press enter or click.

I have tried `change`, `mousedown`, `click`, 'keyup', 'input' events.
JavaScript does not understand user selected hint.

How to read hint values the user selected, from the input field using JavaScript?

Comment: Try `oninput` ?

Comment: Can you show some code, please?

Comment: My guess: Simply a security/privacy feature. It would not be in the user's best interest to let any site snoop all the stuff their form field pre-fill might suggest. Therefor no access for any website script, before the user has explicitly selected a suggested value. _"If i select it, it becomes value of the field"_ - I guess that is just your assumption, based on that you get it _displayed_ in hat position? That doesn't mean it has become the set value of the field.

Comment: I am sorry, i am not sure about the code, because if i simplify it, firefox does not offer me hints. Simplified code is enclosed - it works for listeners, except that firefo does not offer me hints thus i can not chech if they works.  Why simplified code does not get hints? Original code is too long. If i use original code and add any of `input, click, change, mousedown, mouseup` listeners - it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

THe answer is `input` event. Thanks for NewToJS .

Originally it is kind of calendar with user input for YYYY-MM-DD. Calendar was working and all events were working, except that i could not read input with javascript if user clicked on hint - thus i could not display the proper date on the calendar if user selected hint. Nevertheles, the hint date was submited with form and written to database.

Simplified code:

```
function calFnc( date )  { /* calnedar code */ }
calFnc.prototype.handleEvent =  = function(event) {
   console.log(' tagName = '+event.target.tagName+', Id = '+event.target.id+' , class ='+$(event.target).attr('class')+',   type='+event.type);
   if( event.type === 'input' || event.type === 'keyup' ) { /* deal with hint or user input */ } 
 };

var cal1 = new calFnc(); // if date is motted the constructor creates current

document.getElementById('calendar1').addEventListener("click", cal1, false);
document.getElementById( 'calendar1' ).addEventListener("keyup", cal1, false);
document.getElementById( 'calendar1' ).addEventListener("change", cal1, false);
document.getElementById( 'calendar1' ).addEventListener("mousedown", cal1, false);
document.getElementById( 'calendar1' ).addEventListener("mousedown", cal1, false);
document.getElementById( 'calendar1' ).addEventListener("input", cal1, false);
```